# Error on boot 12.04

Tags: boot

When I boot my Toshiba Tecra(nvidia) say no `protocol specified` (2x and ..) a lot of. Then appears the next message:

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable

wainting for X server to shutdown ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated successfully(0). Closing log file.

xinit: server error
xauth: error in locking authority file /home/toshiba/.Xauthority
```

Comment: Does this happen before or after you log on?

Answer (score 21):

I think I resolved my problem. I used  [this forum post](http://ubuntuforum-pt.org/index.php/topic,70938.45.html). The commands were:

```
cd /home/machine
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.old
touch .Xauthority
chown machine:machine .Xauthority
```

Answer (score 2):

[Fixing Error in locking authority file .Xauthority](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216022126/https://www.namhuy.net/1077/fixing-error-in-locking-authority-file-xauthority.html)

```
# cd /home/user
# ls -a -lh
# chown user:user .Xau*
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some explanations from the link.the link can go down any time

Comment: Thankfully, the Wayback Machine (archive.org) exists, and we still have a [version of this page from 2015-02-16](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216022126/https://www.namhuy.net/1077/fixing-error-in-locking-authority-file-xauthority.html).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer suggested by Ricardo, I also want you to do the following:

```
cd /home/machine
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.old
touch .Xauthority
chown machine:machine .Xauthority
```

In cases where chown produces an error, just provide execute and read write permissions, which should solve the problem.

```
chmod +x .Xauthority
```

Answer (score 1):

> cd /home/machine
>
> mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.old
>
> touch .Xauthority
>
> chown machine:machine .Xauthority

Only works if you do it as root user