# Problem upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.04.01

Tags: upgrade

2 months ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04., but today the Update manager showed me some recommended updates, one of these upgrade to 14.04.1 LTS. After installations the pc restarted, but cannot run Ubuntu GUI. Only show the command line black screen and ask me my login and password. I do not know what to do to fix this problem, I tried to reinstall nvidia drivers, but it did not work. Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: I tried to enter to the GUI through recovery mode, but appeared the next message: /usr/bin/X: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Ubuntu Server edition? If so try doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

You should get the GUI.

Comment: No, I have Ubuntu 64 bits Desktop Edition. I already tried it, but did not work. Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the command `startx`?

Comment: xauth timeout in loking authority file /home/juan/.Xauthority
xauth timeout in loking authority file /home/juan/.Xauthority

/usr/bin/X: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Conection refused
xinit: server error
xauth timeout in loking authority file /home/juan/.Xauthority

Comment: Try this to resolve the .Xauthority error http://askubuntu.com/a/166115

Comment: I followed the steps, but anything happened. :(

Comment: Is the error of `startx` the same?

Comment: Yes, is the same.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393495/icc-compiled-code-unable-to-load-shared-object-libimf-so

Comment: I decided to install again the OS, thanks for your support and time.